# How to include individual values into CSS RGB

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, rgb

Can someone help with the JavaScript implementation? I dont know how to include individual values into the css rgb function. The basic idea behind this is that it takes RGB values(0-255) from the user using input forms(html) and then input those number values into the css rgb function using javascript and change the color of the background.

```js
function color()
{
  let rrr = document.querySelector("#Red").value;
  let bbb = document.querySelector("#Blue").value;
  let ggg = document.querySelector("#Green").value;
  let body = document.querySelector("body");
  body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(rrr,bbb,ggg)";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body style="text-align:center">
  <header>
      <h1>Customize My Webpage</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
      <h2>Select Background Color</h2>
      <h3>Steps</h3>
      <p>1) Type value between 0 and 255  for each color.<br>
         2) If you wish to not include a particular color , type 0 in the corresponding field.<br>
         3) 0 denotes no intensity of color , 255 includes highest intensity of color.
       </p>
       <h4>
       <form onsubmit ="color(); return false">
       <button>Red</button><input id="Red" type="number">
       <button>Blue</button><input id="Blue"  type="number">
       <button>Green</button><input id="Green" type="number">
       <input type="submit" value="Color it!">
       </form>
      </h4>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: `body.style.backgroundColor = \`rgb(${rrr},${bbb},${ggg})\`;` (Javascript doesn't care if you use `rrr` inside a string, you need to tell it to actually use the variable)

Comment: complementing above comment, you must concatenate the string with the variables... `".backgroundColor = rgb(" + rrr + "," + ...` or use the string with template literals

Answer (score 2):

You want to use template literals to pass the values of the variables you created, not just their names.

```
body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${rrr},${ggg},${bbb}`;
```

The above code actually extracts the values of those variables and puts them into the background color.

[This doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation) from Mozilla should help explain it, specifically the part on expression interpolation.